# How to loop through multiple dictionaries to extract value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and I want to solve this problem.
I have many product unique ids (i.e. 5331008574423, 5331118575423, 5901008573323) for everytime a transaction is made on a product there are two numbers associated with them that represent a supplier (i.e. 5GHF5, 89YOUT,892HG) and a transaction id (SPE4A718PE141, SME4A788PE147, SYE4B58PE333)

I want to get a count for the amount of transaction that took place for each product. So I decided to count the transaction IDs associated with each productid.

I created a dictionary for each productid

and then add each transaction to the respective productid 
and lastly append all the productID dictionaries into one big dictionary so that I can loop through each and get a count of all the transaction Ids for each productid.

I initiated the dictionary

```
 ProductIDs ={}
 BigDictionary = {}
```

and add each transaction to the dictionary like this

```
ProductIDs[transaction_id] = suplier_id
```

I was trying to do something like this

```
5331118575423: [89YOUT, SPE4A718PE141], [SME4A788PE147,892HG], [89YOUT,SPE4A718PML90]
```

and then append the dictionary above to the BigDictionary

```
  BigDictionary.append(ProductIDs)
```

and loop through each of the product id to get a count of all the transactionID

```
        for productID, ProductTrans in BigDictionary:
```

at this point I'm stuck, is there a better approach to this problem and how would I loop through each productID and print the product id and transaction id count?

Comment: All those explanations distract me. Can you show how the inputs are and what you expect as output for those inputs?

Comment: Why are you indexing the *ProductIds* dictionary with transaction ids? Shouldn't the keys be product ids, and the values lists of transaction ids?

Comment: Please vote an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a dictionary that defaults to a list on each element like `{[], [], []... }`, and to do that you should execute:

```
from collections import defaultdict
product_transactions = defaultdict(list)
```

at this point you can append transactions with supplier id like this:

```
product_transactions[product_id].append((transaction_id, supplier_id))
```

now to count the transactions per product you could do:

```
for product_id, transactions in product_transactions.items():
    print(len(transactions))
```